Munkres Lemma 55.3: Use of quotient maps
In Lemma 55.3 in Munkres, we have:

Let $h: S^1 \rightarrow X$ be a continuous map. Then, the following conditions are equivalent:
(1) $h$ is nullhomotopic.
(2) $h$ extends to a continuous map $k: B^2 \rightarrow X$.
(3) $h_*$ is the trivial homomorphism of fundamental groups.

The proof for $(1) \implies (2)$ is as outlined:

Let $H: S^1 \times I \rightarrow X$ be a homotopy between $h$ and a constant map. Let $\pi: S^1 \times I \rightarrow B^2$ be the map $\pi(x, t) = (1 - t)x$.
Then $\pi$ is continuous, closed and surjective, so it is a quotient map; it collapses $S^1 \times 1$ to the point $\mathbf{0}$ and is otherwise injective. Because $H$ is constant on $S^1 \times 1$, it induces, via the quotient map $\pi$, a continuous map $k: B^2 \rightarrow X$ that is an extension of $h$.

I am having trouble understanding the language of how the quotient map "induces" the continuous extension of $h$ and why the use of a quotient map is relevant here.

From my understanding, $\pi$ is a "radial" map of each slice $S^1 \times t$ onto the unit disc $B^2$, where $S \times 0$ gets mapped to the outer rim of the unit disc, and $S \times 1$ gets mapped to the origin, and $S^1 \times t$ gets mapped to a smaller circle inside the unit disc.
Then, the continuous extension $k$ would be defined as:
$$
z \mapsto \begin{cases}
(H \circ \pi\vert_{C}^{-1})(z) & z \neq \mathbf{0}\\
x_0 & z = \mathbf{0}
\end{cases}
$$
where $C = S^1 \times I - S^1 \times 1$ and $x_0$ is the point in $X$ such that $h$ is nullhomotopic to the constant path at $x_0$. This explicit definition makes use of surjectivity of $\pi$ and the property that $\pi$ is injective everywhere except $S^1 \times 1$.
I think that the quotient map might be used in showing the continuity of $k$, but I am not seeing it.


The key here is the universal property of the quotient (Theorem 22.2 in Munkres): In this case, it says that a map $f\colon S^1 \times I \to X$ factors over the quotient map $\pi\colon S^1 \times I \to B^2$ to give a map $\tilde{f}\colon B^2 \to X$ satisfying $f = \tilde{f} \circ \pi$ if it respects the quotient relation, i.e. if $f$ is constant on $S^1 \times {1}$, which is precisely the condition for $f$ to be a nullhomotopy.
